# Feature Vector Representation Neural Networks

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, feature-extraction

**Objective:** Digit recognition by using Neural Networks

**Description:** images are normalized into `8 x 13 pixels`. For each row ever black pixel is represented by `1`and every white white `0`. Every image is thus represented by a vector of vectors as follows:
[image]

**Problem:** is it possible to use a `vector of vectors` in Neural Networks? If not how should can the image be represented?

1. Combine rows into `1` vector?
2. Convert every row to its decimal format. Example: *Row1: 11111000 = 248* etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining them into one vector simply by concatenation is certainly possible. In fact, you should notice that arbitrary reordering of the data doesn't change the results, as long as it's consistent between training and classification.

As to your second approach, I think (I am really not sure) you might lose some information that way.

Comment: Concerning the vector of vector representation. Can we for instance consider every row as a `single value` not a single.

Comment: @HaniGoc I'm not an expert on neural networks, but in principle, if your input layer has less nodes than you have features, you're compressing the data already. So I suppose it's possible to do so; from my experience though pushing the whole image as a 1D feature vector works well enough.

Comment: While it's "possible", the general viability of this feature mapping is questionable imho. See my response below. In his case concatenation is also not "reordering of the data" but restructuring the network itself.

Answer (score 1):

To use multidimensional input, you'd need multidimensional neurons (which I suppose your formalism doesn't support). Sadly you didn't give any info on your network structure, which i think is your main source of problems an confusion. Whenever you evaluate a feature representation, you need to know how the input layer will be structured: If it's impractical, you probably need a different representation.

Your multidimensional vector:
A network that accepts 1 image as input has only 1 (!) input node containing multiple vectors (of rows, respectively). This is the **worst** possible representation of your data. If we:

- flatten the input hierarchy: We get 1 input neuron for every row.
- flatten the input hierarchy completely: we get 1 input neuron for every pixel.

Think about all 3 approaches and what it does to your data. The latter approach is almost always as bad as the first approach. Neural networks work best with **features**. Features are not restructurings of the pixels (your row vectors). They should be META-data you can gain from the pixels: Brightness, locations where we go from back to white, bounding boxes, edges, shapes, masses of gravity, ... there's tons of stuff that can be chosen as features in image processing. You have to think about your problem and choose one (or more).

In the end, when you ask about how to "combine rows into 1 vector": You're just rephrasing "finding a feature vector for the whole image". You definitely don't want to "concatenate" your vectors and feed raw data into the network, you need to find **information** before you use the network. This is critical for pre-processing.

For further information on which features might be viable for OCR, just read into some papers. The most successful network atm is [Convolutional Neural Network](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html). A starting point for the topic feature extraction is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction).

Answer (score 1):

1 ) Yes combine into one vector is suitable i use this way
http://vimeo.com/52775200

2) No it is not suitable because after normalization  from rang ( 0-255 ) -> to range ( 0 - 1 ) differt rows gives aprox same values so lose data